# How to pass methods to a Tkinter button widget command option from a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a list of methods .
And trying if i can pass them to a button widget command option .I am getting 
Error message

```
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

How can i assign methods list in side a the method_pointer tuple to nav_button command option .

```
class ADB(Frame):
       __init_(self,parent):
         sel.parent=parent
         self.nav_button=[]    
         for i in range(0,2):
             self.nav_button.append(Button(self.parent)




       def start(self) :
            ...........

       def setup(self):
            ...........
       self.nav_bttn_y=15
       method_pointer={'self.start','self.setup'}


        for i in range(0,2):

            self.nav_button[i]["command"]= lambda :method_pointer[i]()
            self.nav_button[i].place(x=10,y=self.nav_bttn_y)

            self.nav_bttn_y +=40
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to have each button run two functions, one after the other? Just make a wrapper function that contains everything a button should do, and connect the button to that wrapper. Or do you want to connect `nav_button[0]` to `self.start()` and `nav_button[0]` to `self.setup()`? If that's the case, just connect each button to the proper command without a loop. It'll be more readable anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `{'self.start','self.setup'}` is not a tuple, it's a *set*. And sets have no ordering, so `method_pointer[0]` is meaningless.

If you want a tuple, just replace the braces with parentheses:

```
method_pointer = ('self.start','self.setup')
```

---

If you need it to be a set, you can't index it… but you can still iterate it (although in arbitrary order), like this:

```
for i, method in enumerate(method_pointer):
    self.nav_button[i]["command"]= lambda: method()
    self.nav_button[i].place(x=10,y=self.nav_bttn_y)
    self.nav_bttn_y +=40
```

In fact, even with a tuple, that's a good idea.

While we're at it, you don't need `lambda: method_pointer[i]()`; that does the exact same thing as just `method_pointer[i]`, but more verbosely, less readably, and more slowly. (And, likewise, you don't need `lamdba: method()`, just `method`.)

---

But you've got another problem: `'self.start'` isn't a method, it's a string. If you want the `self.start` method, you need to pass that, without quotes.

---

So, putting it all together (and fixing your `IndentationError`, and partially PEP8-ifying it):

```
method_pointer = (self.start, self.setup)
for i, method in enumerate(method_pointer):
    self.nav_button[i]["command"] = method
    self.nav_button[i].place(x=10, y=self.nav_bttn_y)
    self.nav_bttn_y += 40
```

Of course I can't promise that this is the last bug in your code, and if you're doing *other* things wrong, it still may not work. But this at least fixes the first three problems.

Comment: When i change the code according to  ur suggestion i dont get  error message but clicking the self.nav_button does nothing , it does not eneter the self.start() or self.setup method

Comment: @Deepworks: Yep, you've got _another_ problem in your code. It may not be the last one. The method `self.start` and the string `'self.start'` aren't the same thing. Take off the quotes. I'll edit the answer to explain. But if you have further bugs in your code, you may want to create a new question rather than just hope to catch me with a followup comment.

Comment: ok i got the point , removing the quotes does it . for time being it solves the problem  i am newbie so dont know about more bugs , taking them one at a time .Thanks a lot